# How to create page using Kendo Gird and Tabstrip

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to select a row of grid and show detail row at tabstrip. The same image should attach.

Can anyone help me? I am using asp.net mvc 4 + Kendo Ui controls.

Image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89knq.png).

File ***CandidateController.cs***

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Can_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(GetAllCan().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Can_ReadId([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Guid id)
    {
        return Json(GetCanById(id).ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In partial view: ***Candidate Info***

```
@model RecruitmentOnlineMVC.Models.CandidateViewModel

    <div class="candidate-detail" style="width: 827px!important">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Candidate Name</th>
                <td>@(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CandidateName, new { @class = "k-input k-textbox" }))</td>
                <th>ID</th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { @class = "k-input k-textbox" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "k-input k-textbox" })</td>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "k-input k-textbox" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

In ***View Index***

```
@model RecruitmentOnlineMVC.Models.CandidateViewModel
    @(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
      .Name("splitter")
      .Panes(panes =>
          {
              panes.Add()
                   .Content(@<div>
                       @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RecruitmentOnlineMVC.Models.CandidateViewModel>()
                                        .Name("grid")
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(c => c.CandidateName);
                                            columns.Bound(c => c.ID);
                                        })
                                        .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                                                    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                            .Ajax()
                                            .PageSize(20)
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("Can_Read", "Candidate"))
                                         )
                                        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(3))
                                        .Filterable()
                                        .Sortable()
                                        .ColumnMenu()
                                        .Events(e => e.Change("onSelected"))
                                    )
                   </div>)
                   .Scrollable(true)
                   .Collapsible(true)
                   .Size("370px");

              panes.Add()
                   .Content(@<div>
                       @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                                      .Name("tabstrip")
                                      .Items(tabstrip =>
                                          {
                                              tabstrip.Add().Text("Candidate Detail")
                                                      .Selected(true)
                                                      .LoadContentFrom("/Candidate/CandidateInfo");

                                              tabstrip.Add().Text("Work History")
                                                      .LoadContentFrom("/Candidate/WorkHistory");

                                          })
                                )
                   </div>);
          }))
```

***Script***

```
<script>
function onSelected() {
    var can = this.select();
    var propId = this.dataItem(can).ID;
```

\\In here, I want call action at Controller with propId and return detail on Tabstrip

Can anyone help me?
Thank so much !

---

I want to handled according to process like this :

[image: here]

Please guide me. Thank so much!

Comment: its easy...first all your juqery and function should be in your main share-->_Layout(masterpage) and all the contents will be accessible from _Layout and you can add what ever you wanted in any of the tab strips..  tab strips api link...have a look: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/tabstrip/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a seprate function in you controller with Json http post
and calls ajax request from the OnSelected() function..

following is the example
//Get Company List

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCandidateDetails(string propId)
    {
       var Model= repository.GetCnadidatedetails(propId);  

        return Json(Model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

---

```
<script>
function onSelected() {
    var can = this.select();
    var propId = this.dataItem(can).ID;
     var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
            $.ajax({    

                url: '@Url.Action("GetCnadidatedetails", "Controller")',  
                //note: only string type is allowed as paramater to send to controller                  
                data: { propId : this.propId }, 
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                statusCode: {
                    404: function () {
                        showMessage("page not found.");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {

                    alert("error");

                },
                success: function (result) {

                    //add your result to tabstripe
                    $("#tabstrip").add(result.Id+result.Name); 

                }
            });
```